# Laravel 5.6: Can't access class variable inside constructor

Tags: php-7, laravel-5.6

I have a custom class in the App\MyClasses folder. I want to set a variable within the class and only access it from various methods inside the class, so it can be private.

When I create a class instance from within a controller, I get an error "Undefined variable: configuration" in the constructor. Can you tell me what I'm missing here?

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and PHP 7.2. Thanks!

```
private $configuration;

/**
 * Create a new instance of the connector.
 * @param $userid The logged in user's ID
 * @return void
 */    
public function __construct($userid) {
    //get the configuration object
    $config = User::find($userid)->configuration;
    //dd($config); //OK - has correct data
    $this->$configuration = $config; //'undefined variable: configuration' error here
}
```

Comment: To access member variabes in php you don't need the second `$`. Try `$this->configuration = $config;`

Comment: OMG yes! I completely missed that little bugger. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem, good luck!